# Multiple horizontally stacked side-by-side listings

Tags: listings, minted, horizontal

I am using [`acmart`](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf). They define a full-text (two-column) listing environment `listing*`. If I put multiple `minted`s inside it, they are stacked vertically. I would like to have them side-by-side. Is that possible?

What about some type of sub-listing environment, that allows me giving them each their own description?

```tex
\begin{listing*}[thp]
  \caption{caption}
  
  \begin{minted}{javascript}
code1 {
}
  \end{minted}

  \begin{minted}{javascript}
code2 {
}
  \end{minted}

  \begin{minted}{javascript}
code3 {
}
  \end{minted}
\end{listing*}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the all-blank lines between `\end{minted}` and `\begin{minted}{javascript}`?

Comment: @Mico Just tried it. Sadly, did not help :/

Comment: Is there maybe a different way using `minipage` and some way to have sub-listings inside that minipage on a grid?